# Extjs Override makeButton

Tags: javascript, extjs, icons, overriding

I have a problem with Ext Js 4.2.1. I want to override the makeButton function in Ext.window.MessageBox.
This is my code:

```
Ext.override(Ext.window.MessageBox,{            
                makeButton: function(btnIdx) {
                    var btnId = this.buttonIds[btnIdx];
                    var buttonIcons = {
                        ok: 'iewp-icon-ok',
                        yes: 'iewp-icon-ok',
                        no: 'iewp-icon-cancel',
                        cancel: 'iewp-icon-cancel'  
                    };
                    return new Ext.button.Button(
                    {
                        handler : this.btnCallback,
                        itemId : btnId,
                        iconCls: buttonIcons[btnId],
                        scope : this,
                        text : this.buttonText[btnId],
                        minWidth : 75
                    });
                }
            });
```

Ext.override is called in the init function of my application and it works at that point for other overrides.

The change works, if I change the function directly in the ext-all-dev file line 127299, but not with an override.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: How are you using `Ext.window.MessageBox` then? How exactly do you see that your override is not working?

Comment: I use Ext.Msg.show with a config as parameter, but as described when I change it in the ext-all-dev code it works. And my override/change adds icons to the standard Ext.Msg.YESNO buttons.

Comment: [`Ext.Msg`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox) is a singleton *instance* of `Ext.window.MessageBox`. The instance is created *before* you apply your overrides to its class. I don't think that late changes in an Ext class would be reflected in previously created singleton instances of it.

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem :)
Have a nice day!